# Office 365 - available resources

Tags: sharepoint-online

i am creating a new site collection in sharepoint online, it shows me 5.90 GB available of 18.20 GB showing a green bar, beside that there is another section saying: 0 resources available with red bar, which is confusing. do I have resources to create new site collection or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"0 resources available" refers to **resource quota**.

The resource usage quota is a site collection metric automatically compiled by SharePoint Online. Resource usage generally includes performance data (such as processor time and unhandled exceptions) that pertain to code in sandboxed solutions. When the level exceeds the daily quota, the sandbox is turned off for the site collection. The main purpose of resource quotas is to limit the risk that custom code will negatively impact the site collection.

Usually when you create a site collection when resource quota has exceeded limit, you get error message "You have reached the maximum resource usage limit."

Refer [this link](http://sharepointrevealed.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-increase-server-resource-quota.html) to know how to increase resource quota.

Comment: but i am not selecting any site collection, and yet i can see both indicators, one says 5.9 available, the other 0 available, i didn't really get what you said, i want to know the difference between both of them not only the resource quota.

Comment: The one which says 5.9 available is the "Storage" quota and the one which says "0" available is the resource quota. Storage of content on Tenant will contribute to Storage Quota. While performance data, for e.g any exceptions that arise in custom code, contribute to resource quota.

Comment: If you have not selected site collection, it is showing overall quota available in tenant.

Comment: but how do I have 0 resources available while I don't have any sandboxed or custom code written? I only have 5 test site collections with barely any content inside, so how do i have 0 resources, and only 5 GB left in storage? Also doesn't resource mean storage?

Comment: No resource does not mean storage.Resource quota is related to "Performance Data". You can raise a support ticket with SharePoint online admin center if you are not sure why your storage quota has gone high.

Comment: ok. and for the 0 resources available? is there something am doing that causes it to be like that?

Comment: As per resource quota definition , it is mainly caused due to performance issues.But as you say there is no custom code involved in entire tenant,you can check by following steps given in link in answer to see if any more resource are available. You can increase resource quota if available.